# Passing array to an array in numpy

Tags: python, numpy

```
import numpy as np

arr1= np.array([10,20,30,40,50])
arr2= np.array([False, False,  True,  True,  True])

result=arr1[arr2] #[30 40 50]
```

Having hard time to grasp this. When another numpy array is passed to an existing numpy array, all elements multiplied?

Comment: No, it's called boolean or masked indexing. https://numpy.org/devdocs/user/basics.indexing.html#boolean-or-mask-index-arrays

Comment: See also [Boolean array indexing](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/arrays.indexing.html#boolean-array-indexing).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're *indexing* a numpy array by another array, rather than *passing* an array to another array. In your case, since you're using a boolean index, it's creating a [mask](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.indexing.html#boolean-or-mask-index-arrays), and only returning the values of `arr1` where `arr2` is True.